# Turning multiple layers into one sprite sheet

Tags: flash, animation, sprite, flash-cs6, sprite-sheet

I'm learning flash, and need to generate a sprite sheet of an animation. I was following a tutorial and imported a layer for each appendage of the turtle I'm animating. Each appendage in each layer is a symbol, but when I select all the layers, right click, and do "generate sprite sheet" it exports a png with all of the different symbols disjointed. How do I combine all the layers and keep the animation of each symbol so that it looks like one animation.

Ex: I have one layer called "left leg" (with animation) and one called "right leg"(without animation) and I want to export a sprite sheet of both legs with the one moving. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, if anyone else ever runs into this issue.

Copy all the frames from all of the layers, then go Insert->new symbol and paste them into the first keyframe of the new layer in the timeline of the new symbol.